# Site Mailbox Error Code 0

Tags: site-mailboxes

In our SharePoint environment I have configured site mailbox as per instruction given at technet site. While running the ps1 script to setup mailbox  I have not received any error. All setup has been ok.

But while I have added site mailbox app to one of the subsites and clicking on site mailbox I am always getting error like

> We are facing troubled while contacting with the SharePoint Server and
>   error code is showing as 0

While clicking on SiteMailbox it is not redirecting to exchange server instead giving the error code 0.

I have checked the sharepoint log and found below error is throwing

> SharePoint Portal Server        Site Mailbox                   ajv81
>   Exception  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CollaborationMailboxInternalService.ExchangeHasPermissionsToSiteSubscriptionInternal(SPWeb
>   web, CollaborationMailboxErrorCodes& errorCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CollaborationMailboxInternalService.<>c__DisplayClassf.b__e()
>   StackTrace:  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll:
>   (sig=678c0f87-966f-4d99-9c94-b49e788d2672|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb,
>   offset=131CE) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BE5)
>   b95d899c-c3a4-e04a-1a4b-6d2b28c555e5  04/21/2014 10:47:21.96  w3wp.exe
>   (0x21B8)

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Same situation here, no script errors but when creating the site mailbox on a Project Server 2013 we always get the same error as you, Did you manage to solve it? Thank you

Comment: I have been getting this exact error, have you managed to solve it?